# Aspire E5-571G-55ST RAM slots issue

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, acer-aspire

I have Aspire E5-571G-55ST laptop and tools like CPU-Z and Speccy show that I have 2/4 slots used... Even Windows Task Manager shows that I'm only using 2/4 slots... But when I opened up the laptop to put in 2 RAM's in the 2 leftover slots, I found out that the motherboard has only 2 physical slots, or I'm not seeing good???

The motherboard is:

Acer EA50_HB

Chipset is: Intel Haswell-ULT rev. 0B
South bridge: H8x/P8x rev. C1

Bios:

Insyde corp. v 1.32

Can someone help me out to figure this out? Does it have 2 or 4  slots?

Edit: Here are the pictures:

[image]

[image]

If you guys would agree, I think tools like Speccy & CPU-Z can indeed make a mistake... But it shows I have 4 slots on Windows's task manager as well !!! This is really odd...

Comment: can you post a photo?

Comment: Hi, I posted the pics of results... Is that the pics that you needed?

Comment: How many slots does the manual for your laptop say it has?

Comment: I can't find the paper sheet manual right now... But I remember when I was buying, it said 4 slots... Edit: did you guys find any info on the laptop itself? :)

Answer (score 1):

Aspire E5-571G-55ST laptop has only two slots in actual.
Supports max of 16 GB ( 2 x 8 GB).

All Aspire E5-571G has two slots only. You just have to disregard the 4 slots as reported by CPU-Z or Speccy.